# To create the rule using guided rule in redhat/drools

Tags: drools, redhat

I have created the guide rule file, in the when part I need to define the response. In the when part I need to declare the list as add the object in the list. The list object again assign to the my response object that have list of Element.

I have the class BreElement. The have the object breElement. I need to map this object to my Propert calls. That have list of BreElemnt.

I am not able to add the BreElement to the list.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and also read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Stack Overflow is not a free script writing service. Your own research and code attempts are expected. Edit the question to include your code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.